# Install VLC 3 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, vlc

Is it possible to install VLC 3 on Raspberry Pi 3?

I know that for Ubuntu is possible using a `ppa`, but didn't found anything similar for Raspberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/ has "armhf" binaries, which is the rPi platform.

Note that Debian:Jessie == Ubuntu:Trusty.

Comment: Thanks! Now, since `armhf` build is failing, I'm not able to install it, but I will try again once package will correctly build.

Comment: @Danibix Are you saying the _install_ from the PPA fails? Or are you building your own from source?

Comment: Installing from `ppa`.